# Socket message reading delay in spring-integration?

Tags: java, spring, sockets, spring-integration

I'm using `spring-integration` to send data to a server socket, and read from it.

Problem: the **read** from the received socket data stream takes mostly 1000ms!
I'm testing against a local socket server that is responding instant.

The root cause must be somewhere in the spring framework, because I changed the spring-integration part to a native socket implementation, and this one works instantly.

```
@Bean
@Primary
public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientFactory() throws Exception {
    TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean fact = new TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean();
    fact.setType("client");
    fact.setHost("127.0.0.1");
    fact.setPort("9876");
    fact.setUsingNio(true); //delay is gone if I change this to false
    fact.setSingleUse(true);
    fact.setSoTimeout(timeout);
    fact.setDeserializer(new MyDeserializer());
    fact.afterPropertiesSet();
    return (AbstractClientConnectionFactory) fact.getObject();
}

/**
  * The same routine applied on a native java socket works instantly!
  * But the time measured if used in spring-integration is always at least 1000ms!
  */
static class MyDeserializer implements Deserializer<String> {
    @Override
    public String deserialize(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {

            StopWatch w = new StopWatch();
            w.start();

            String str;
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(str).append("\n");
            }

            w.stop();
            System.out.println("time taken: " + w.getTotalTimeMillis());

            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Mostly the deserializer time is about 1005-1010ms. On my native socket, the same routine is 5-10ms. So somewhere on the `TcpNioConnection.ChannelInputStream` from spring must be something that's causing a second delay here?

Sidenote: I just discovered the delay is gone if I change `fact.setUsingNio(false)`. How might using nio affect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting - it's a bug - I opened [INT-4465](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4465).